# Unable to show uiimagepickercontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I can not access `UIImagePickerController` defined in `AppDelegate`.I already defined `UIImagePickerController` object in `AppDelegate.h` file also used its delegate. This is my code.

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 

    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];  
    picker.delegate = self; 
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    picker.allowsEditing=NO;

    return YES;
}
```

And I am using action sheet in viewcontroller file and want to perform this action as -

viewController.m

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
switch (actionSheet.tag) 
    {
        case 1:
            switch (buttonIndex)
        {
            case 0:
            {
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                [appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:appDelegate.picker animated:YES];
                    }
           }
     }
}
```

But image picker controller view is not showing.

Comment: which iOS version are you testing on? `presentModalViewController` is a deprecated method. You should use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead.

Comment: Check if you have assigned delegate properly in .h file. That is <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>...

Comment: [appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:appDelegate.picker animated:YES completion:nil];   also not working.

Comment: Everything is ok.I connected both UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate in .h file.

Comment: where you init your window and set the window.rootViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

don't write

```
 [appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:appDelegate.picker animated:YES];
```

instead try to write

```
 [appDelegate.window presentModalViewController:appDelegate.picker animated:YES];
```

Let me know it is working or not.!!!
Happy Coding!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe objective c now auto synthesizes your properties and is expecting _picker for the ivar. Use for notation to acces your picker like self.picker or self.delegate.picker